# Suggestions for optimizing code that sorts data into multiple sheets - needs to be faster for 100k+ rows

Tags: excel, vba

How could I make my code faster...?  I tried two different approaches to achieve what I need to, but they are rather slow when I work with ~140,000 rows of data.

The data is found in one sheet, and four additional sheets exist which have the names

```
LogName(1) = "Log_1"
LogName(2) = "Log_2"
LogName(3) = "Log_3"
LogName(4) = "Custom_Log"
LogNameSz = UBound(LogName) - LBound(LogName) + 1
```

Each data row contain one of these labels per row, and all of these labels are in the same column (see example below):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ArD6g.png)

The spirit of the code is the following: for each row, look at the row's label, copy the entire row of data, and paste it into the sheet with the corresponding name.

These are my approaches:

```
''FIRST METHOD
'For j = 1 To LogNameSz
'    cnt = 4
'    Set celE = ColLog.Find(LogName(j), LookIn:=xlValues)
'    fstadd = celE.Address
'    'Debug.Print fstadd
'    Do
'        celE.EntireRow.Copy Worksheets(LogName(j)).Rows(cnt)
'        Set celE = ColLog.FindNext(celE)
'        cnt = cnt + 1
'    Loop While celE.Address <> fstadd
'Next j
```

```
''SECOND METHOD
'    For s = 1 To Lastrworig
'        If CkList(ColLog.Rows(s).Value, LogName, LogNameSz) = True Then
'            Set ColEValue = Worksheets(ColLog.Rows(s).Value).UsedRange
'            Lastrwlog = ColEValue.Row + ColEValue.Rows.count - 1
'            ColLog.Rows(s).EntireRow.Copy Worksheets(ColLog.Rows(s).Value).Rows(Lastrwlog + 1)
'        End If
'    Next s
```

The reason why cnt = 4 is because the four additional sheets have 3 rows that have been added to the top of the sheets, and the data needs to be pasted starting on the 4th row.  This is also the same reason why I look for the last row of each sheet by using UsedRange in my second method.

Does anyone one have suggestions for how to make either of these methods faster?

Comment: Looping through every single row is what takes so long. You should make your code sort the data, find the first row you need, find the last row you need, and then just copy that range over to the new tab.

Comment: @Hooded0ne - Yes, you're right... I modified my code to filter the data and then just copy over.  Thanks for the insight.

Answer (score 0):

### Copy +100k Criteria Rows

```vb
Sub CopyData()

    Const SRC_NAME As String = "Master"
    Const SRC_CRITERIA_COLUMN As Long = 5
    Const SRC_FIRST_CELL As String = "A2"
    Const DST_FIRST_CELL As String = "A4"
    
    Dim dNames(): dNames = VBA.Array("Log_1", "Log_2", "Log_3", "Custom_Log")
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = wb.Sheets(SRC_NAME)
    Dim srg As Range
    With sws.UsedRange
        Set srg = sws.Range(SRC_FIRST_CELL, .Cells(.Rows.Count, .Columns.Count))
    End With
    
    Dim cCount As Long: cCount = srg.Columns.Count
    
    Dim sData(): sData = srg.Value
        
    Dim dict As Object: Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    dict.CompareMode = vbTextCompare
    
    Dim dKey
    For Each dKey In dNames
        Set dict(dKey) = New Collection
    Next dKey
    Erase dNames
    
    Dim sr As Long, srString As String
    
    For sr = 1 To UBound(sData, 1)
        srString = CStr(sData(sr, SRC_CRITERIA_COLUMN))
        If dict.Exists(srString) Then dict(srString).Add sr
    Next sr
    
    Dim dws As Worksheet, dData(), srItem, dr As Long, c As Long
    
    For Each dKey In dict.Keys
        ReDim dData(1 To dict(dKey).Count, 1 To cCount)
        dr = 0
        For Each srItem In dict(dKey)
            dr = dr + 1
            For c = 1 To cCount
                dData(dr, c) = sData(srItem, c)
            Next c
        Next srItem
        Set dws = wb.Sheets(dKey)
        dws.Range(DST_FIRST_CELL).Resize(dr, cCount).Value = dData
    Next dKey

    MsgBox "Data copied.", vbInformation
    
End Sub
```

Comment: This looks like awesome code...! :) I'm actively working through it to see how it works.  Thanks very much for the suggestion.